# How to solve this algorithm in Prolog code? (production systems)

Tags: prolog

I'm amongst the biggest newbies of Prolog and I'm trying to understand how can the following riddle can be written as Prolog code:

"In order to illustrate a production system in action, we consider the
following task. We have three bricks, each of different size, sitting in
a heap. We have three identifiable positions in which we want to place
the bricks with a robotic “hand”; call these positions 1, 2, and 3. Our goal
is to place the bricks in those positions in order of their size, with the
largest in position 1 and the smallest in position 3."

So how does this work actually? I assume firstly, will need to have a working memory described as such:

```
(brick name: brick1 size: 3 position: heap)
(brick name: brick2 size: 4 position: heap)
(brick name: brick3 size: 5 position: heap)
```

The goal would be brick3 in position 1, brick2 in position 2 and brick 1 in position 3.

I also know that I need 2 production rules, the first one will put the biggest brick in hand, and the other one will place the brick from the hand in the next position, but how do I represent these rules as Prolog code and what command would I run in order to get the result?

Edit: I only know that my rules should be:

```
IF (brick position: heap name: n size: s) 
−(brick position: heap size:{> s}) 
−(brick position: hand) 
THEN MODIFY 1 (position hand) 

IF (brick position: hand) 
(counter value: i)
THEN MODIFY 1 (position i) MODIFY 2 (value [i + 1])
```

Comment: Show your attempt please

Comment: I only know that my rules should be:

    IF (brick position: heap name: n size: s)
    −(brick position: heap size:{> s})
    −(brick position: hand)
    THEN MODIFY 1 (position hand)

    IF (brick position: hand)
    (counter value:i)
    THEN MODIFY 1 (position i)
    MODIFY 2 (value [i + 1])

Comment: @Florianz - You should have a go at doing this. Try to at least define, in valid prolog code, what the prolog facts might be to get started. Then try to what an operation might look like to map the current state to a new state after a move. Do as much as you can until you are stuck and then post that code. Otherwise we're not a code writing service so your question would be off-topic.

Comment: Try to formulate your rules in a way that aligns with Prolog predicate definition. A predicate looks like, `head :- q1, q2, ..., qn.` which means `head` is true if `q1` is true and `q2` is true and... `qn` is true.

Comment: thank you, all, i'm gonna do that and return